# Преобразование матриц .NET

Tags: c#, .net, математика

Всем привет.

Задача. Дана матрица: размера `[m,m]`, составить новую матрицу, в которой вырезается k-я строка и n-й столбец (n и k задается пользователем), соответственно размер новой матрицы  `[(m-1),(m-1)]`.

[image: снимок]

Вот мой код

```
private static void CreateMatrix(int[,] ints, int value, int k, int n)
{
    int lengthResult = value - 1;
    int tempColum = 0;
    int limitColum = n - 1;
    int limitLine = k - 1;
    var massiveResult = new int[lengthResult, lengthResult];

    for (int colum = 0; colum < value; colum++)
    {
        if (colum != limitColum)
        {
            int tempLine = 0;
            for (int line = 0; line < value; line++)
            {
                if (line == limitLine)
                {
                    if (limitLine != lengthResult)
                    {
                        massiveResult[tempColum, tempLine] = ints[colum, ++line];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    massiveResult[tempColum, tempLine] = ints[colum, line];
                }
                tempLine++;
            }
            tempColum++;
        }
    }
    DisplayArrayOf(massiveResult, lengthResult);
}
```

Он рабочий, но вопрос в том, как его оптимизировать или решить задачу по другому не так тривиально?

Заранее всем спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Далеко не самый оптимизированный и тривиальный вариант решения и на выходе получаем не двумерный массив, **ИСКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНО** в ознакомительных целях!

```
int m = 5;

var matrix = new int[,]{{10,11,12,13,14},
                        {20,21,22,23,24},
                        {30,31,32,33,34},
                        {40,41,42,43,44},
                        {50,51,52,53,54}};

int k=1, n=3;

Enumerable.Range(0,m)
    .Select(el=>Enumerable.Range(0,m)
                    .Where(elem=>elem!=n))      // Удаляем столбец
    .Select((el,i)=>el.Select(j=>matrix[i,j]))
    .Where((el,i)=>i!=k)                        // Удаляем строку
```